# How to fix Errno::ENETUNREACH while connecting to CoinEx via websocket?

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I'm trying to communicate with CoinEx (cryptocurrency exchange) API via WebSocket using Ruby 2.6. I have the following code:

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'

url = 'wss://socket.coinex.com/'
# url = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ltcbtc@miniTicker'

EM.run do
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new(url)

  ws.on :open do |event|
    p [:open]
    ...
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    p [:message]
    ...
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    ...
  end
end
```

When I run this code, I always see `[:close, 1006, ""]` immediately, without `[:open]`. I hacked deeply into gems (faye/websocket and eventmachine) and added some debug output to have better understanding of what is going on. Now my traceback is as follows:

```
/home/chernish2/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/faye-websocket-0.10.9/lib/faye/websocket/client.rb:87:in `unbind'
/home/chernish2/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1483:in `event_callback'
/home/chernish2/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run_machine'
/home/chernish2/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in `run'
/home/chernish2/soft/trader2/test/ws_test.rb:36:in `<main>'
emit_error(), message=Errno::ENETUNREACH
[:close, 1006, ""]
```

Which really doesn't make any sense to me since another URL

```
url = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ltcbtc@miniTicker'
```

works just fine, and when I'm using https://github.com/altangent/ccxws library (nodejs) it connects to CoinEx using exactly the same URL as in my code without any troubles which means I don't have problems connecting to CoinEx WS endpoint.
So what is wrong with my code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: based on your code alone, there doesn't appear to be anything"wrong" with it.  Have you posted the contents of `ws_test.rb:36` ?  There are only 24 lines of code in what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it is working now, without any changes from my side. Seems like there was some problems on the server side.